# Does geokit-rails use "point" columns and spatial indexes when using mysql?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, geokit

If it doesn't, how is the performance compared to me rolling my own using point/spatial indexes? When looking for records within N miles of another record.

To be more precise I have a table with a million records in it with lat & long data. I need to be able to find all records within N miles of any given lat/long point? Would geokit do this quickly? (compared to mysql spatial index?)

Looking into geokit-rails mysql adapter it looks like it does the brute force math comparison vs using mysql index to do the work (but maybe I don't understand the code)